# I tried today to go to admin page and got this error

Tags: admin, error, page

Warning: include(`Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php`): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in `/home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/lib/Varien/Autoload.php` on line 96

```
#0 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(96): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage/Ad...', '/home/abogacec/...', 96, Array)
#1 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(96): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Admin_Mode...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Mage_Admin_Mode...')
#4 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1346): class_exists('Mage_Admin_Mode...')
#5 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('admin/observer', Array)
#6 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::getModel('admin/observer', Array)
#7 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('admin/observer')
#8 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#9 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#10 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#11 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#12 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/abogacec/public_html/dycgarage.ro/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the php version is changed?

Comment: I looked now, It's not changed

Comment: Now I saw that I got the same problem on 3 different websites, I don't understand what is going on

Comment: can be that the database is full?

Comment: Hmm, It's not this either